# Getting adwords history using awql

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api, awql

I am building an app where users can authorize and we take their data daily and also on initial authorization we pull the last 365 days of data.

So far I can pull data, but it gives me totals of the last 365 days, I wanted to know if adwords api has any features like analytics api in which you can set dimensions to grab the data for each day of the 365 days.

```
$reportQuery = 'SELECT Date, CampaignId, AdGroupId, Id, Impressions, Clicks, Cost, Conversions, CostPerConversion FROM CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING 20160101, 20160702';

$reportUtils = new ReportUtils();
$data = $reportUtils->DownloadReportWithAwql($reportQuery, null, $user, "CSV");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply include `Date` in your AWQL query then adwords will give you the data segmented by date.

details of the segments, metrics and attributes available are listed here:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/criteria-performance-report#date